# How to make a auto updater for my toolser

Tags: git, github, batch-file, updates, auto-update

I'm making a toolset, made entirely with batch files, added to PATH for everyday use. the problem is, i need a way to somehow look for a update when the computer starts, cloning the repo with the last version. the path for the app is C:\Program Files (x86)\EnhancedCMD
and also, the content of the folder is a bunch of .bat files.

i tried to create a batch file with

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\
git clone https://github.com/ItsDoomOne/EnhancedCMD
```

and saved in the startup folder.
it cant overwrite the folder.
help pls

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can schedule tasks using the Task Scheduler, this tasks can be triggered by different events, like logging in, on Windows start, on a date, at a specific time, etc.

You can write a script that checks if the repo exists in disk by checking if the directory exist, if the repo doesn't exist then `git clone` it, then `cd` to the repo and call `git pull` which will update the repository with the latest changes.

try with

```
if exist "C:/Program Files (x86)/EnhancedCMD" (
  echo updating
  cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/EnhancedCMD"
  git pull
) else (
  echo creating
  cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/" 
  git clone https://github.com/ItsDoomOne/EnhancedCMD.git
)
```

and save to a file then use the task scheduler to run this file on any event you'd like and make sure to run as administrator, `git pull` will work assuming that the repository has a default upstream so you don't have to specify a remote repo and a branch

Comment: just updated the repo, runned the updater and it doesnt made changes to the directory

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a `cd` command, and also the script needs to run with administrator privileges